# What type of template from WP can be suitable for the site with the game "Quiz"

Tags: wordpress, templates, layout

The task is to create a website with a personal account. On the site will be a game of "Quiz". What template would you recommend to use or better to make a website from scratch? Are there such suitable templates on WordPress or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, It mostly doesn't depend on **Theme**, rather depends on what you make to the website like using Css and jQuery to make UI enhancements.

Also use the below link for best plugins that help you build your **QUIZ** game with numerous features.

https://www.wpbeginner.com/showcase/best-quiz-plugins-for-wordpress/